# We have all our PowerShell scripts written in 5.1 version. We got a new client who uses only Linux servers. Do we need to re-write all scripts?

Tags: linux, powershell, operating-system, cross-platform

We have a set of PowerShell framework scripts for data collection which runs perfectly in PS 5.1 version. Now, our client has no Windows machine. Their data centre runs on a Linux platform.

What is the best way to deal with this problem?

1. Should we re-write scripts in PowerShell 7 to support both the windows and Linux platforms?
2. OR should we choose Dockers platform?
3. OR Is there a better option?

Any guidance is really appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: That depends entirely on what dependencies (.dll's) your scripts have and whether they can be migrated to .NET Core

Comment: We have a couple of Azure modules which are in .dll, but this is not a major ask. I did some testing of our existing scripts in v7.0 and there quite a few errors. I think the secure string doesn't work on Linux platform. I am still learning about the PowerShell 7.x core

Comment: I'd strongly suggest re-writing your question as "How to fix [error X] when migrating from 5.1 to 7.1?" and then include the specific code and error details you're having problems with. As it currently stands, your question is likely to get closed for either being too broad, lacking details or asking for opinions :)

Comment: sorry for my broad question, and I didn't want to put all errors, so I thought of getting the best option to choose right from the beginning.  We have 86 PowerShell scripts which we should make them cross-platform compatible.

Comment: Sounds like you just need to break the migration down into smaller steps? You could start by testing the scripts in 7, one by one, and reviewing all the errors - some of them might be obvious and easy to fix on your own, others might simply be effects of previous errors not being handled. Once you get to a point where the you've fixed all the issues you can, ask about the remaining ones.

Comment: I was the same thought in my mind to start off with, I started with using PSScriptAnalyzer module and tried testing one the scripts. But the script did prompt any warning for [link](PSUseCompatibleCommands) even though I was using `compress-Archive' in my code and this is not supported in 3.0. 
I have to make my scripts work both on windows and Linux platform

Comment: Why are you worried about 3.0, I thought you were going for 5.1 and up? In any case, I think you need to configure [target platform profiles](https://github.com/PowerShell/PSScriptAnalyzer/blob/master/RuleDocumentation/UseCompatibleCommands.md) to take full advantage of `PSUseCompatibleCommnads`

Comment: I have edited one script and runs without error in PowerShell 7.0.3, but the same script throws an error when I test in RHEL 7 OS. I was wrong in thinking that it works in version 7 it is not compulsory to work in Linux. I think I need to re-write the scripts with mix of Bash commands in the powershell script. I am I right?

Comment: Given that you still haven't posted a single line of code or error message: _how would anyone here be able to tell_? No one but you can see your screen :)

Comment: $fSpace = [math]::Round((Get-CimInstance -ComputerName localhost  …`
    ` |`                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | The term 'Get-CimInstance' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling
     | of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

Comment: that is the error I get when I run on Linux OS. I think Get-CimInstance is not supported in Linux

Comment: The `CimCmdlets` module is not available on Linux, no. If you want any qualified advise, please [update your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64229458/edit) with the code and errors